# Controller can return either JSON or HTML depending on the result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I have a pop-up window that contains a form. I must have a controller that processes the form, and depending on the result, this controller returns either JSON (if all goes well, and popup can be closed by javascript) or HTML (if the form data is not valid and form must be replaced with a new html - with the validation error messages).
So I found just such a solution: that's form:

```
<form id="message" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

And I have jquery handler for this form:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#message", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if ($.isPlainObject(result)) {
                // this is JSON
                // close the pop-up window
            } else {
                // this is HTML
                $("form#message").html(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    ...
    if (.. is valided ..)
        return Json(new { success = "OK" });
    else
        return View(model);
}
```

The question - are there more elegant solutions for such tasks?

Comment: Why won't just return html inside json key for clarity and simply check if error key is set?

Comment: @fliespl, it's a bit of a PITA to render ASP.NET MVC views to strings on the server and serialize those partials to JSON.

Comment: Is it really? If I remember correctly your can simply render partial with just a few lines - probably the same number as in your code :)

Comment: @fliespl, yeah, there are some hacks to do that, but I have always found them, well, *hacks*.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am no expert in ASP.NET - I just remember redering partials in such situations - good to know that those are regarded as hacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO this is a very nice solution to this problem and something I would definitely use.

Comment: Agreed, there is nothing wrong with your solution. Looks fine to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I just thought that similar tasks occur often, and maybe there's some kind of standard solutions. So that not to reinvent the square wheels, unawaring that around the world have long enjoyed the round wheels :)

Answer (score 2):

Look fine with your approach. But if your JSON error message is common for all screens to use, I would like to suggest that you can write a action filter in this case. So we can make a code more elegant

```
[HttpPost]
[JsonErrorHandling]
public ActionResult UpdateMessage(MessageModel model)
{    
    return View(model);
}

public class JsonErrorHandlingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter 
{
   void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      // TODO: doing some thing magic here
      // if (.. is valided ..)
      //  return Json(new { success = "OK" });

      this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
}
```

Comment: in my case, controller returns JSON if all is ok. Errors are returned into HTML. And 'TODO' must be executed on the client side - in java script. But thanks for your answer - it will be useful to me in another place ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return multiple datatypes from the URL then there is no need to pass the dataType in jQuery AJAX call.`

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    //dataType: "json",  comment this line
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {}
  });
```